# How to make production-quality frequency tables in RStudio?

Tags: graphics, output, rstudio, frequency

I've found a number of R packages (`AMR`, `expss`, `knitr`) that create nice frequency tables. However, the tables are generated in the Console using simple text characters instead of being generated as a graphics file (as happens when RStudio plots are generated in the Plots window).

Comment: For `expss` you can print `expss_output_viewer()` and then all tables will be outputed in the RStudio Viewer.

Comment: Ah, and the `summarytools` package lets you output tables to the RStudio viewer as well: `library(summarytools); data(mtcars); view(freq(mtcars$cyl))`.